# Perl parameters passing with special characters

Tags: perl

This is a pure Perl parameters passing issue. I cannot use `Get::Opt` as it is not installed on every machine.

I need to pass parameters with spaces and other special chars sometimes. Three scripts to demo the process. Is there a better way to do this?

```
[gliang@www stackoverflow]$ perl parameter_wrapper.pl
prep.pl #<5> parameters
prep_v2.pl #<5> parameters
<aaa_777-1>
<bbb-6666-2>
<Incomplete QA>
<-reason>
<too long, mail me at ben@example.com :)>
```

---

```
cat parameter_wrapper.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
# call prep.pl with 5 parameters
my $cmd = "./prep.pl aaa_777-1 bbb-6666-2 'Incomplete QA' -reason 'too long,  mail me at ben\@example.com :)\n'";
system($cmd);


cat prep.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @parameters = @ARGV;
my $count = scalar(@parameters);

my @parameters_new = wrap_parameters(@parameters);
my $cmd = "./prep_v2.pl @parameters_new";
print "prep.pl #<$count> parameters\n";
system($cmd);

sub wrap_parameters {
    my @parameters = @_;
    my @parameters_new;
    foreach my $var(@parameters) {
        $var = quotemeta($var);
        push(@parameters_new, $var);
    }
    return @parameters_new;
}


cat prep_v2.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @parameters = @ARGV;
my $count = scalar(@parameters);
print "prep_v2.pl #<$count> parameters\n";

foreach my $var (@parameters) {
    #print "<$var>\n";
}
```

Comment: Getopt::Long has been part of the Perl core since Perl 5 was first released in 1994.  Are you sure it's not available on the machines you're looking to deploy on?  In your comment you refer to it as "Get::Opt", so could you have made a mistake while checking the machines?

Comment: I might be wrong, but we have redhat73 to CentOS7, macs, Ubuntu and others, hundreds of scripts already written, like prev_v2.pl, all we can change is to change  parameters_wrapper.pl and prep.pl to feed in or filter out and pass along to script like prep_v2.pl, which have their own parameters handling, thanks

Comment: @gliang Okay, then rewrite prep.pl and parameter_wrapper.pl to use Getopt::Long (and while you're at it, combine them into a single script, what you have now with `system` calling another script just for arg processing is wonky). You shouldn't be writing your own code to handle command line options, there are too many difficult edge cases; you're re-inventing square wheels.

Comment: About your specific error: the line `$var =~/^\Q$var\E/;` isn't doing what you think it is. That simply checks whether `$var` matches itself, so `wrap_parameters` isn't actually changing anything. You want `$var = "\Q$var\E";` or `$var = quotemeta($var);` (although you shouldn't be using this approach, either; see my previous comment.)

Comment: quotema() really removes the error. I never knew this sub. thanks. I cannot really reduce the level, there are unknown system call to prep.pl, prep.pl simply redirect version appropriate that is not in common path. My previous implementation is uglier, remove all special chars from beginning, feed the next program with a string. Your comment really helps, thanks

Comment: @AndyLester, I checked our computers, actually have Getopt::Long installed already, please copy your comments, I plan to accept your comments, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getopt::Long has been part of the Perl core since Perl 5 was first released in 1994. Are you sure it's not available on the machines you're looking to deploy on? In your comment you refer to it as "Get::Opt", so could you have made a mistake while checking the machines?